# php $_SESSION variables not carrying from a flash game?

Tags: php, session, variables

So I made this flash game and all appropriate variables are entered. If a user is logged in, it SHOULD enter the variable $_SESSION[user] into the mysql database to store the user's score. For some strange reason, it doesn't do that. What makes it even stranger is that I can echo the $_SESSION[user] variable correctly, but when thrown into a mysql DB, it returns NULL (as 0). Here's the code that does all the processing.

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html>
<?php
include("../package.php");      //stuff for UI

echo $_SESSION[user];           //this works

if($_SESSION[user]){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `DB`.`TABLE` (`user`,`type`,`game`,`score`) VALUES ('$_SESSION[user]', '$_POST[type]', '$_POST[g]', '$_POST[score]')");
?>
     //Congratulations message in HTML
<?php
}
else{
?>
   //Tells you to login (the 'else' statement to if($_SESSION[user])) also in HTML
<?php
}
?>
```

I don't see anything wrong....

Comment: You should really enable error reporting when you debug scripts. Then you would know that you have multiple errors in there. Look for warnings. Basically `'{$_POST['type']}', '{$_POST['g']}', '{$_POST[score]}''` - but anyway this will get some kiddies a lot of fun exploiting your database because of sql injection - http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: `echo $_SESSION[user];           //this works` should give you the first error (most certainly ../package.php has more errors).

Comment: sql injection from a flash game? how is that possible? i didnt give them any fields to type into...

Comment: It's no problem to see which values are acutally passed from the flash game into your script. It's easy then to change those values and exploit your script, e.g. by deleting the whole content of your database or just to cheat scores or whatever. So whenever you create SQL queries, ensure that the data get's properly validated and sanitized as well as properly encoded into the SQL string. I suggest you making use of PDO and prepared statements. You can then easily use placeholders for your values.

Comment: You open your PHP-driven webpage from within the flash page? The problem probably is, that the session information (most likely a cookie) is not being used by Flash's request to your script, thereby a new session is started each time you make a request to your webpage.

Comment: yeah thats what i figured, it says all of the session variables are undefined :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your logic to this, for debugging purposes:

```
$sql = <<<EOL
INSERT INTO `DB`.`TABLE` (`user`,`type`,`game`,`score`)
VALUES ('$_SESSION[user]', '$_POST[type]', '$_POST[g]', '$_POST[score]')
EOL;

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("query: $sql\n\n" . mysql_error());
```

That'll give you the full text of the generated query, as well as the exact error message MySQL produced. If the query succeeds, then things continue as normal. If there was an error, then you'll be told why.

Most likely the error is due to your mis-quoting of session values:

PHP's polite and will translate your `$_SESSION[user]` into `$_SESSION['user']` (note the quotes). But when you do this from within a double-quoted string, all bets are off.